# strtok() return NULL in the middle of the parsing

Tags: c, strtok

I'm try to parse a line in this format :

```
1: 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
```

so Im using the `strtok()` function with 2 delimiters  and `,` (space and comma)
But for some reason when i get to 6 the funcion return NULL.

```
fileName = strtok(line, spaceToken);
fileName[strlen(fileName) - 1] = 0; //remove the ':'
...
//doing something with fileName
...
fileName = strtok(NULL, commaToken);
while (fileName != NULL) <-----THE PROBLEM
    ... 
    //doing something with fileName
    fileName = strtok(NULL, commaToken);
}
```

So when the fileName should be `6`, i get `NULL`.

With this input :

```
file1: file2,file3,file4
```

Where i sould get `file2` for the `fileName` I'm getting `'fil'` , and the next iteration will be `NULL`.

This is the full code if it's help

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <memory.h>

#define MAX_LINE_NUMBER 11
#define MAX_FILE_NAME_NUMER 255
#define MAX_FILES 10

//function declaration
void parseFile(char path[]);

int contain(char fileName[]);

int addToDependencieArray(char fileName[], int currentFileIndex);

enum COLOR
{
    WHITE, GRAY, BLACK
};

typedef struct MyFile
{
    char name[MAX_FILE_NAME_NUMER];
    int neighbors[MAX_FILES];
    int neighborsCounter;
    enum COLOR myColor;
    int predecessor;
} MyFile;


//global
MyFile gDependencies[MAX_FILES];
int gCurrentFilesWriten = 0;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    parseFile(argv[1]);
    puts("hello");
}

void parseFile(char path[])
{

    FILE *fPointer = fopen(path, "r");
    char line[MAX_LINE_NUMBER];
    char spaceToken[2] = " ";
    char commaToken[2] = ",";
    char *fileName;
    int currentFileIndex = 0;
    int sourseFile = 0;
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fPointer))
    {
        fileName = strtok(line, spaceToken);
        fileName[strlen(fileName) - 1] = 0; //remove the :
        int sourse = contain(fileName);
        if (sourse == -1) // isn't contains
        {// to create function add.
            currentFileIndex = addToDependencieArray(fileName, currentFileIndex);
            sourseFile = currentFileIndex - 1;
        }
        else // contain
        {
            sourseFile = sourse;
        }
        fileName = strtok(NULL, commaToken);

        while (fileName != NULL)
        {
            if (contain(fileName) == -1)
            {
                currentFileIndex = addToDependencieArray(fileName, currentFileIndex);
                int neighborIndex = gDependencies[sourseFile].neighborsCounter;
                gDependencies[sourseFile].neighbors[neighborIndex] = currentFileIndex - 1;
                gDependencies[sourseFile].neighborsCounter++;
            }
            fileName = strtok(NULL, commaToken);
        }

    }
    fclose(fPointer);
}

int contain(char fileName[])
{
    int res = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < gCurrentFilesWriten; i++)
    {
        if (!strcmp(fileName, gDependencies[i].name))
        {
            return i;
        }
        else
        {
            i++;
        }
    }
    return res;
}

int addToDependencieArray(char fileName[], int currentFileIndex)
{
    strcpy(gDependencies[currentFileIndex].name, fileName);
    gCurrentFilesWriten++;
    gDependencies[currentFileIndex].neighborsCounter = 0;
    currentFileIndex++;
    return currentFileIndex;
}
```

Comment: `fileName[strlen(fileName) - 1] = 0;` Note: strlen() can return zero. (and filename could even be NULL in this case)

Comment: Thank you, but i can assume there wont be any empty line.

Comment: Why not write a small main program with hard-coded data instead of assuming things are "ok"?

Comment: I was just pointing you at a bad habit. Fix all bad habits and you'll almost be perfect...

Comment: Thank you :) that's a good advice

Comment: What are your `//doing something with fileName` blocks doing? Could they be overwriting the buffer that `strtok()` is working from?  Perhaps (at least while debugging) `strcpy()` the results of `strtok()` into a suitably-sized buffer and do the "something" with that buffer?

Comment: @TripeHound What im doing is to check if the file name conains in Array and if not add it. 
But  i think that the problem isnt there because the while iteration compile the block as  i intended.Sould I write the function im using , i fear it will be out of context

Comment: You are not expected to fiddle around (i.e.: change) with the string currently under analysis by `strtok()`- Neither are you allowed to nest `strtok` calls for different strings, as the library has only one place to store context (you should be using `strtok_r` in this case). Your problems are most probably caused by breaking one of those rules.

Comment: Well as i look again Im using 'strcpy()' when im adding the 'fileName' into the array. But it's weird because it adding some of the chars until '6'

Comment: Maybe you should first read strtok()s manpage. (and probably decide to never use strtok() for the rest of your life) -->> strtok() places a '\0' into the string itself, you don't need to do that.

Comment: @joop even when im commenting this line the problem remain.

Comment: You should provide complete example code that reproduces the problem... no comment placeholder allowed, unless the problem remains the same without the commented code. Same for your so called *array*... it's not written in your question, so how would we know what you do and how you do it?

Comment: @grek40 I've added the full code.

Comment: Sidenote: you double-increment `i` in your `contain` function, so it will not return the correct results. Didn't check if any subsequent problem arises from this.

Comment: @grek40 Well that was a problem i didnt saw , Thank you ! 
but the main problem still fighting :(

Comment: I know how to find the root of the problem: debugging! Put a breakpoint at every call to `strtok`, compare the input to your expectations, compare the output to your expectations and compare the initial string input (`line`) to your expectation. If you found the first point where expectation and reality doesn't match, try to find out why this happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#define MAX_LINE_NUMBER 11
...
char line[MAX_LINE_NUMBER];
...
while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fPointer))
```

You are only reading the first 11 characters of the line!  Increase `MAX_LINE_NUMBER` **and rename it** to something like `MAX_LINE_LENGTH` and it should work.

Explanation: [when reading using fgets](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets),

> fgets() reads in at most one less than *size* characters from stream

Your examples:

```
123456789a|bcdef <-- character number - fgets only reads through _a_
1: 2,3,4,5|,6,7,8,9,10  <-- 5 is the last thing you read
file1: fil|e2,file3,file4 <-- "fil" is the end of the string
```

Comment: OMG ! thank you ! im trying to understand this with the debugger for 3 hours !THANK YOU

Comment: @limitless what did you actually debug? Looking at the `line` variable for a second should be enough to understand, that the problem long happened before the first `strtok`.

Comment: @grek40 my mistake was that i was looking at the fileName all the time.kinda taking for granted the line because I've changed the MAX_LINE from 1001 to 100, but accidentally changed it to 11.